# Tensorflow with Keras fit and tensors in dataset input result in list index out of range

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I encountered a strange error when using tf.keras in python with a dataset that consists out of tensors.

What I do is create a dataset from a csv file and modify it as it contains a time series. In the end, I end up with a dataset that has tuples of input and output tensor.

These are fed into a tf.keras model and here is where it becomes interesting. Fit calls a function in training.py of the keras enginge which is called _standardize_user_data. This should return the input, targets, and so on for fit_loop, which in turn checks something on it and crashes with

```
if issparse is not None and issparse(ins[i]) and not
K.is_sparse(feed[i]):
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

in line 187 of training_arrays.py. This is due to the fact _standardize_user_data returns empty lists, with the reasoning that if tensors are the input, then it everything should be set up already, which it apparently isn't. that Here is some small MWE.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import glob
import logging
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


def read_dataset(filename, columns, field_defaults, input_size, output_size, stride, input_features):
    def decode_csv(row):
        fields = tf.decode_csv(row, record_defaults=field_defaults, field_delim=',')
        all_columns = dict(zip(columns, fields))
        return all_columns

    def split_window(window):
        inputs = tf.reshape(tf.concat(window['value'][0:input_size], axis=1), [input_size, input_features])
        outputs = tf.reshape(tf.concat(window['value'][input_size:input_size + output_size], axis=1),
                             [output_size, input_features])

        return inputs, outputs

    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames=filename)
    dataset = dataset.map(decode_csv)
    dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.sliding_window_batch(window_size=input_size + output_size, stride=stride))
    dataset = dataset.map(split_window)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()

    return dataset


if __name__ == "__main__":
    COLUMNS = ['value']
    FIELD_DEFAULTS = [[0.0]]
    INPUT_FEATURES = 1

    epochs = 1
    steps = 1
    INPUT_SIZE = 4
    OUTPUT_SIZE = 2
    STRIDE = 1
    input_train = "./data/"

    input_train_list = glob.glob(input_train + "*")

    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(OUTPUT_SIZE, activation=None))
    set = read_dataset(input_train_list, COLUMNS, FIELD_DEFAULTS, INPUT_SIZE, OUTPUT_SIZE, STRIDE, INPUT_FEATURES)

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01), loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
    model.fit(set, epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=steps)
```

The data is in the form of:

```
0.047910000000000785
3.0999999999892225e-05
0.0160979999999995
2.9000000000500847e-05
0.01716599999999957
2.800000000036107e-05
2.9999999999752447e-05
0.019235000000000113
```

Does anybody know if this is intended or if something goes wrong? Does my data generation give the wrong output? Or could it be that there is a bug?

I'm thankful for any help!

Comment: I haven't used tf datasets, so I'm not sure if this is related, but I had the same crash and realized that I hadn't supplied `model.fit` with output labels for the input data. After setting `model.fit(x=input, y=output)` the crash went away.

Comment: @askielboe I asked the same question on their Github and it is indeed a bug and was already fixed in the nightlies. I guess it will be fixed in the next stable release, 1.11, as well.